# How to switch CultureInfo at runtime in C# for a nuget packet?

Tags: c#, nuget, globalization

we are working in Visual Studio 2017 and wannt to provide a c# class library project, using .NET Framework 4.6.1, via nuget. The problem is the project uses resource files.

The project structure is like this:

- ProjectFile.csproj
- MainLibClass.cs
- Resource.de-De.resx
- Resource.en-Us.resx
- Resource.resx

  - Resource.Designer.cs

The MainLibClass accesses the resources like this:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;

public class MainLibClass
{
...
   public void SetCurrentThreadToCulture(string cultureName)
   {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture   = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureName);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureName);
   }

   public string foo()
   {...
      string resourceValue = Resource.ResourceManager.GetString(valueNodeName);
      return resourceValue
   }
}
```

This project works and is tested for different cultures (en-US, de-DE, ...)

I than created a nuget package.
From the console, in the folder of the ProjectFile.csproj  file, I started :

```
nuget spec
nuget pack ProjectFile.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects
```

or

```
nuget pack ProjectFile.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects -symbols
```

I than created a small test console-application (using .NET Framework 4.6.1), where the new nuget packet is installed properly.
The test application does something like:

```
MainLibClass reader = new MainLibClass();
reader.SetCurrentThreadToCulture("de-DE");//"en-US"
string resValTranslated = reader.foo();//Contains only Resource.resx data
```

Now the translation does not work anymore!
Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Can i build the resources into the nuget dll, or do i have to restructure the nuget, or, or...???

***EDIT:***
If i use the nuget structure of Rui Jarimba referenced article [Creating localized NuGet packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-localized-packages) 
And if i include every language specific resx files beside every language specific dll and if i set the culture before accessing the nuget class the first time, than it works!
So if i change the test application to:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture   = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");

MainLibClass reader = new MainLibClass();
string resValTranslated = reader.foo();//Now it works!
```

***EDIT 2:***
But this approach only works once!
If i do :

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture   = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");

    MainLibClass reader = new MainLibClass();
    string resValTranslated = reader.foo();//Now it works!

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture   = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");

    MainLibClass reader2 = new MainLibClass();
    resValTranslated = reader2.foo();//Now it dont!
```

***EDIT 3 @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen  :***
As i already said in the first EDIT the nuget file contains unziped the following structure:

- lib

  - net461

    - de-DE

      - MainLibClass.resources.dll
      - Resource.de-DE.resx
    - en-US

      - MainLibClass.resources.dll
      - Resource.en-US.resx
    - MainLibClass.dll
    - Resource.resx

Comment: Do you confirm the nuget package is generated correctly, i.e. `.resx` files are included? Also, see [Creating localized NuGet packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-localized-packages)

Comment: How did you do the installation?  Did you publish?  Framework uses windows dlls and unless the dlls are the same on the Build and Deploy PCs that code isn't going to work the same.  Publishing an application will make sure the correct dlls are installed on the deploy machine.

Comment: @jdweng I did it local on my maschine

Comment: @Rui Jarimba, i just tried to structure the nuget like in your referenced article. If I compile the ProjectFile.csproj, i get a dll per language, but i only include the compiled dlls per language and not the resources  and it does not work!

Comment: The most obvious reason is that the nuget package installer forgets to copy the satellite assemblies and ensures they get copied to the project's build directory.  Not simple to do, you would have mentioned it.

Comment: A nuget package is a zip file, unzip it and look at its contents, are all the resource  assemblies present?